# How can I view the timestamp for History items in Firefox Android?

Tags: firefox-for-android, history

I need to view the exact times I visited certain pages in Firefox mobile for Android. Is there a way to do this, or export the data to view it somehow?

Comment: It may possible with backup. Do you want to view the data in Android or in a PC? What's the Android version in your Mobile?

Comment: Do you use Firefox's sync? If you do you can have the history synced to your PC and there you can see exact times for when you opened a page.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an idea:

First, you need to setup Firefox Sync. It's simple: [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer)'s the Mozilla help page, or you can search for one of the many tutorials.

Once you set that up you will have your history (and bookmarks, tabs, etc.) synced between your android device's Firefox and Firefox on your PC.

On your PC in Firefox open the history (`Menu` -> `History` -> `Show all history`).
In that window's menu bar go to `Views` -> `Show Columns` -> `Most Recent Visit`.

Now you can see the page there in the history with the exact time of the last visit next to it.

Comment: I wanted a more exact time than that, which only shows minutes, and have given an answer on Super User SE to https://superuser.com/questions/1568047/how-can-i-see-when-i-last-visited-a-web-site-accurate-to-better-than-one-minute .

Comment: I wanted a solution that allows my devices to remain independent.  Is the Android Firefox UI still so limited that it is impossible to find out when you visited a site by any easy means?  (Not that Chrome is much better - it groups visits by date but has no apparent user access to the time of day.)

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1349952 - has link in answer to GitHub issue for this feature to be added to the phone version of Firefox.